# Weka will not open on MacOS

Tags: weka

I have installed the latest version of Weka(3.9.3). I have also ensured that both Java and MacOS are up to date on my machine.

When I double-click the Weka icon to open it, it bounces for a few seconds and never opens.

I have downloaded Weka 3.8.3 to see if that makes any difference, but the same thing happened.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Confirmed. I just downloaded `weka-3-9-3-oracle-jvm.dmg`, copied the contents to a folder, got past Apple’s security restrictions by context-clicking to choose `Open` to run `weka-3-9-3-oracle-jvm.app`. Eventually the app icon jumped a couple times on the Dock. Then nothing.

Comment: I suggest you contact the vendor, or other discussion groups. At this point, this is not a programming problem. So it is not appropriate to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it, Basil. I’ll contact the vendor instead.

Comment: Similar issue on High Sierra and Mojave for me. Here's a workaround from a shell: `java -jar /Applications/weka-3-8-3-oracle-jvm.app/Contents/Java/weka.jar 
` .  You can add an alias to your .bash_profile if you'd like.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing a similar issue but it worked for me when I start weka on the command line.

1. Change directory into the weka-3-8-0 directory

   `cd /Applications/weka-3-8-0`
2. invoke the jvm with the weka.jar file located in the above directory

   `java -jar weka.jar`

Comment: This is the method to go. The standalone setup provided doesn't seem to work in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

We have identified the issue with the WEKA 3.8.3 and WEKA 3.9.3 applications for the Mac that, for many users, caused them to fail to start up via double-clicking.

On December 13, we replaced weka-3-8-3-oracle-jvm.dmg and weka-3-9-3-oracle-jvm.dmg on SourceForge with a new .dmg compatible with older versions of OS X, based on the HFS+ file system. Unfortunately, this new “release" included a pre-17 December 2018 version of the Amazon Corretto JVM 1.8.0_192 instead of the Oracle Java VM we had used before. Unfortunately, that particular version of Amazon’s Corretto had a bug on Macs:

"The libfontmanager in Corretto is linked to the libfreetype in X11 and breaks when X11 is not installed."

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/change-log.html.

We never noticed this problem and could not reproduce it because if, like us, you had XQuartz installed, or the libfreetype.dylib library was installed on your Mac via Homebrew, the WEKA application still worked in spite of this bug.

We have reproduced the problematic behaviour by removing XQuartz and Homebrew on one of our Macs. And, indeed, the WEKA macOS application no longer started when the bird was double-clicked.

We have just made new “releases” of the WEKA 3.8.3 .dmg and the WEKA 3.9.3 for the Mac that use the latest version of Corretto 8 (8.212.04.2). You can find these .dmg files at

https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-3-8/3.8.3/

and

https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-3-9/3.9.3/

respectively.

They are called

weka-3-8-3-corretto-jvm.dmg

and

weka-3-9-3-corretto-jvm.dmg

respectively.

We have also replaced the links for the Mac applications on the main WEKA downloads page at

https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html